# Kerras the definition of a model changes when the input tensor of the model is the output of another model

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I need to provide the output of model1 as the input of model2.

```python
A=keras.layers.Input(batch_shape=(3,500,500,3))
B=keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=3, kernel_size=3)(A)
model1=keras.models.Model(A,B)
C=keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=3, kernel_size=3)(B)
model2=keras.applications.vgg19.VGG19(input_tensor=B, weights='imagenet', include_top=False, pooling='avg')
#Error: You are trying to load a weight file containing 16 layers into a model with 17 layers.
```

As the error message suggest, keras failed to realize vgg net correctly.

A vgg19 net contains 23 layers (without top). But if the input tensor is the output of another model, the number of layers changes.

```python
vgg19_normal=keras.applications.vgg19.VGG19(input_tensor=A, weights=None, include_top=False, pooling='avg')
len(vgg19_normal.layers)
#23

vgg19_abnormal=keras.applications.vgg19.VGG19(input_tensor=B, weights=None, include_top=False, pooling='avg')
#input tensor B is the output of model1
len(vgg19_abnormal.layers)
#24
```

So keras complains that the number of layers is not equal.

Comment: I think there is a fundamental problem with what you are trying to do: the shape of `C` is (3, 496, 496, 8) and is not compatible with what VGG19 expect. The input shape to VGG19 should have exactly 3 channels.

Comment: OK, I've edited my post, but problem remains.

Comment: It seems this is realted to https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/7013

and it's not solved yet.

Answer (score 0):

I still have some doubts, for example I don't understand what `C` is there for. Anyway this is my current idea:

```
A=keras.layers.Input(batch_shape=(3,500,500,3))
B=keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=3, kernel_size=3)(A)
model1=keras.models.Model(A,B)
C=keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=3, kernel_size=3)(B)
vgg19=keras.applications.vgg19.VGG19(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, pooling='avg')(model1.output)
model2=keras.models.Model(inputs=A, outputs=vgg19)
```

The resulting topology of `model2` is

[image]

To produce this image I used [keras.utils.plot_model](https://keras.io/visualization/).

Comment: To make my problem clearer, I've edited my post again. Indeed, my problem can be solved by loading vgg weights without specifying the  input tensor, but I think the weights loading problem is a bug.

Comment: `model2` is disappeared from your question. Try to be more clear on what you want to do. About the bug you mention, I think it is better discussed on Github but it may not be a bug at all. You just have to construct the computational graph in the right way.

Comment: By the way, how do you draw the picture in your reply?